# How can change Rotation values without rotating

Tags: transforms

I have a 3D model and it have rotation values like -76 , 80 , 90. I want to rotation values 0,0,0 but without rotating only must values changing. It is possible ?

Comment: Ctrl + A > Rotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Please make sure you are in **Object mode** 
Hit **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>** and select **Rotation** form pop up menu

As shown step by step below: 
[image]

All zeros
[image]

Best of luck :)

Comment: Please mark it correct answer, if it worked for you

Comment: Make sure to press "N" if the Transform pane shouldn't be visible!